# Why is Eloquent searching where Active =?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, App\Song (belongsTo App\Host) and App\Host (hasMany App\Song).

In my controller I am using the following query:

```
$songs = Song::whereHas('host', function($query) {
   $query->eligable()->activeHost();
})->inDownloadedQueue()->get();
```

This is derived from the following query scopes in my `Song.php` model
public function scopeEligable($query)

```
{
    $query->where('skip_threshold', '>', \DB::raw('songs.attempts'));
}

public function scopeActiveHost($query)
{
    $query->where('active', 1);
}

public function scopeInDownloadQueue($query)
{
    $query->whereNull('downloaded');
}
```

This doesn't return any results, turning to `->toSql()` function to debug the query is as follows:

```
select * from "songs" where exists (select * from "hosts" where "songs"."host_id" = "hosts"."id" and "skip_threshold" > songs.attempts and "active" = ?) and "downloaded" is null
```

This `host = ?` seems to be the problem. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is a SQL parameter. Eloquent uses PDO parameterized queries, which helps prevent SQL injection.

The query itself will show `active = ?`, but when the query is executed, it will bind your value (`1`) to this parameter, and the query that is actually executed will be `active = 1`.

The queries are fine, you're just not getting any results because you don't have any songs in your downloaded queue that are related to eligible, active hosts.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of PDO queries, it was an issue with data.